# RewriteRule header Content-Type: image/jpeg

Tags: .htaccess, header, content-type, imagejpeg

My site, parsing image from another site, but don't show them. (It shows: ����������������� )

I know what it is, it is a problem with `Content-Type`.
I need to use `Content-Type: image/jpeg`, and all will be ok!

But images are opened by URL (eg. `example.com/DIR1/(100000-999999)/DIR2/(100000-999999)/`). This number is random.

If I write in `.htaccess` (on `example.com`) the following then it works:

`Header set Content-Type: image/jpeg`  - i see photo .

But then all other URLs fail!

How can I : If `DIR1/(.*)/DIR2/(.*)/` - Use `Content-type: image/jpeg` ?

DIR1 , DIR2 = Photos/(number)/image/(number)

Answer (score 0):

Your script that serves the image should really be generating this header as part of the response.

However, to set this conditionally in `.htaccess` just for this form of URL-path then you could do something like this:

```
# Set env var if required URL-path is requested
SetEnvIf Remote_URI "^/DIR1/\d+/DIR2/\d+/$" SET_JPG_CONTENT_TYPE=1

# Only set header when env var is set
Header set Content-Type "image/jpeg" env=SET_JPG_CONTENT_TYPE
```